# I’m trying to programme a plot of the 2D Schrödinger equation in python using the finite differences method

Tags: python, physics

I have began to write a programme that calculates solutions to Schrödingers equation in 2D using the finite differences method. I would like to display the solutions graphically using a contour plot or some other graphical display by taking in user input for the dimensions and number of grid points.

I have simplified the Schrödinger equation by setting hbar^2/2m to 1 and setting the potentiel (V) equal to 0 which gives:

-(dψ^2/dx^2 + dψ^2/dy^2) = E*ψ

Using the finite differences method the left hand side of the equation becomes the matrix of the form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4YES.jpg)

So this now becomes an eigenvalue problem which is the part I’m having trouble implementing.

After using the command np.linalg.eig to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors I’m unsure of how to code a graphical interpretation of these solutions in 2D. Any help will be much appreciated.

Basically I want to use the eigenvalues and eigenvector to graphically display the solutions I just don’t know which to use and how to code it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more precise in your question.  You say you don't know which to use, eigenvalues or eigenvectors, but that depends on what you want to plot.

Do you want to plot the energies of the quantum mechanical system?  Those are represented by the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian operator.

Do you want to plot the states that you observe your system to be in when you measure the energy?  Those are given by the eigenvectors.

After finding the relevant quantity, what is it you want to plot?  If it's just the energies, then you can use matplotlib's [heatmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.htm) tools to show the energy as a function of x and y.  If it's the states of definite energy, then you could use [some of the vector field](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) tools that matplotlib provides.